# How to inject characters into an array, and join that array into a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a url that's split by `=` parameters, what I want to do is inject characters into the array after every `=`:

For example:

```
http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id=82&pid=157&view=print
```

Should be split by the equals sign into an array that looks like this:

```
["http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id", "=", "82&pid", "=", "157&view", "=", "print"]
```

Then I want to add the letter "a" after the equals signs:

```
["http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id", "=", "a", "82&pid", "=", "a", "157&view", "=", "a", "print"]
```

After this is done I want to `join` that array to output:

```
"http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id=a82&pid=a157&view=aprint"
```

What I've tried:

```
module MultipleParameters

  class TestAllParameters

    def check_for_multiple_parameters(site, char)
      site_arr = []
      if site.count("=") != 1
        site.split("=").each do |string_split|
          site_arr.push(string_split)
        end
      end

      inject_syntax(site_arr, char)
    end

    def inject_character(array, char)
      array.each do |param|
        param.inject(char)
      end

      puts array.join("")
    end

  end

end
```

However when I do this, I'm getting the error:

```
detection.rb:18:in `block in inject_syntax': undefined method `inject' for "http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  inspect
        from detection.rb:17:in `each'
        from detection.rb:17:in `inject_syntax'
        from detection.rb:13:in `check_for_multiple_parameters'
        from detection.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

How can I do this successfully? Will I need to `scan` the string and split it when there's a "=" found instead of splitting the string by the equals sign?

Comment: This is what's often referred to as an ["XY question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your question should be, "How can I replace every equal sign in the following string with `'=a'`"? Instead, you've assumed it has to been done in a particular way, which, as it turns out, is not the best approach. @David shows how this should be done. You need to guard against making too many assumptions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland In my time programming I've come to assume that everything I think I know is wrong, I see where you're coming from and I understand how this can be taken as an XY question, but please believe me when I say that was not my intention. I did however assume that it had to be done through an array, and I do agree that this particular question is an XY question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should separate params from url

```
url = 'http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id=82&pid=157&view=print'

array = url.split('/')
```

and now you should change all '=' to '=a' in last element in this array

```
array[-1] = array[-1].gsub('=', '=a')
```

now you can use join on this array :)

```
new_url = array.join('')
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add it to only one of the equals at a time?

Comment: you can use `sub` instead `gsub` for one match

Comment: be careful if you use `sub`, because the second time you use it, it may replace the same `=`, so you get `=aa`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `gsub` method.

```
str = 'http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id=82&pid=157&view=print'

str.gsub('=','=a')
```

This yields

```
"http://multiplexstimulator.com/catalog/product.php?cat_id=a82&pid=a157&view=aprint"
```

Note that `gsub` does not modify the original string, if you want to modify it, use `gsub!`

Comment: it can be dangerous if something '=' will be located in url before params

Comment: is it even possible to have `=` before the query string?

Comment: @BartekGładys What do you mean by dangerous?